# How can I print only the even numbered lines of an array in perl?

Tags: arrays, perl, scripting

I am new to Perl and am trying to write a script that will only print the even numbered lines of an array. I have tried multiple different methods of finding the size to use as the condition for my while loop, but I always end up getting an infinite loop of the first line without the program terminating. The array being input is a text file, input with the form "program.pl < foo.txt". Have I made a logic or syntax error?

```
@input = <STDIN>;
$i = $1;
$size = $#input + $1;
while ($size >= $i) {
        print "$input[$i]";
        $i = ($i + $2);
}
```

Comment: `$1` is the variable that stores captured strings from regexes, and you have no regexes in your code, so most likely `$1` is undefined. Same with `$2`.

Answer (score 4):

Don't call your problem with

```
program.pl < foo.txt
```

Instead, just pass 'foo.txt' as a parameter:

```
program.pl foo.txt
```

Inside your script, rely on default reading from `<>` and the line number variable `$.`:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<>) {
    next if $. % 2;  # Skip odd numbers.
    print;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you already have an array with all of your input, in your example `@input`, you can get all of the even index entries into another array using an Array Slice like so:

```
my @input_even_entries_only = @input[grep { $_ % 2 == 0 } 0..$#input];
```

The expression inside the square brackets evaluates to all of the even numbers between `0` and `$#input`.

You can then use a regular `for`/`foreach` loop to go through the resulting array:

```
for my $val (@input_even_entries_only) {
    print "$val";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to print lines of an array indexed at even numbers then, try this:

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @input = <DATA>;
for(my $i=0; $i<=$#input; $i+=2) {
    print $input[$i];
}

__DATA__
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

#### Output:

```
1
3
5
```

Answer (score 0):

I've no idea what you are doing with the `$1` and `$2` variables. Did you think they were just numbers?

When you use a variable that has not been assigned a value, it is undefined, which will be converted to `0` when used in numerical context. If you do not use `use warnings`, this is done silently, and will be rather confusing.

Other than that, your code is not too far off. It should be something like:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @input = <>;   # <> is more flexible and does the same thing
my $i = 1;
while ($i <= $#input) {
    print $input[$i];
    $i += 2;
}
```

Though of course, storing the entire file in an array is not necessary, and most often you should just loop over it instead. Like [Miller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1733163/miller) has shown in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22851750/725418), which is probably the solution I would suggest. Using a `for` loop like [JS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/970195/js) shows is an excellent way to control the loop.